# I am trying to drag and add image to pdf file and save this pdf with signature using qoppa library,

Tags: android

I am trying to drag and  add image to pdf file and save this pdf with signature using qoppa library,
my functionality running properly but after saving my application get crashed. 
my code is

```
    StandardFontTF.mAssetMgr = getAssets();

    String val = "/sdcard/TEST.pdf";
    Log.e("pdffilename",""+val);

    mStampImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/122.jpg");
    //mStampImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/imagex/"
            //+ signatureName);

    mStampButton = new Button(this);
    Log.e("sing","sing"+mStampButton);
    mSaveDocButton = new Button(this);
    mStampButton.setText("Sign");
    mSaveDocButton.setText("Confirm");
    mStampButton.setHeight(40);
    mStampButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSaveDocButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mNotesView = new QPDFNotesView(this);
    Log.e("sing","sing"+mNotesView);
    mNotesView.setActivity(this);

    // ///////////////
    // mNotesView.loadDocument("/sdcard/Attachment.pdf");
    mNotesView.loadDocument(val);
    // /////////////////////
    // removing unwanted buttons
    if (isOnlyView == true) {

        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbNewDoc());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbOpen());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolInk());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolNote());

        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolTypewriter());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolUnderline());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolUnderline());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolFreetext());

        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolFreeHighlight());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolStrikethrough());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbShowSearch());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolHighlight());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolLine());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolSquare());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolCircle());

    } else {
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbNewDoc());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbOpen());

        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolNote());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(

                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolTypewriter());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolUnderline());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolUnderline());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolFreetext());

        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolFreeHighlight());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolStrikethrough());`enter code here`
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbShowSearch());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolHighlight());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolLine());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolSquare());
        mNotesView.getToolbar().removeView(
                mNotesView.getToolbar().getIbToolCircle());

        mNotesView.getToolbar().addView(mStampButton);
        mNotesView.getToolbar().addView(mSaveDocButton);
        mSaveDocButton.setClickable(false);
    }
    setContentView(mNotesView);

}

class ImageDrawingTool extends AnnotDrawingTool {
    private PointF m_CurrAnnotCenter;
    private Matrix drawingMatrix = new Matrix();

    public ImageDrawingTool(Context arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    protected Annotation initAnnot(PointF point) {

        point = convScreenToPdf(point);


        stamp = AnnotationFactory.createRubberStamp(mStampImage);
        // center rectangle around given point
        stamp.setRectangle(new RectF(point.x - mStampImage.getWidth() / 2,
                point.y - mStampImage.getHeight() / 2, point.x
                        + mStampImage.getWidth() / 2, point.y
                        + mStampImage.getHeight() / 2));

        m_CurrAnnotCenter = new PointF(stamp.getRectangle().centerX(),
                stamp.getRectangle().centerY());

        drawingMatrix.preScale(getViewer().getCurrentScale(), getViewer()
                .getCurrentScale());

        return stamp;
    }


    @Override
    public void dragged(MotionEvent e) {
        // reposition the Stamp according the the user dragging

        PointF draggedPoint = convScreenToPdf(e.getX(), e.getY());

        float deltaX = draggedPoint.x - m_CurrAnnotCenter.x;
        float deltaY = draggedPoint.y - m_CurrAnnotCenter.y;

        m_CurrAnnotCenter = draggedPoint;

        RectF currRect = m_Annot.getRectangle();
        currRect.offset(deltaX, deltaY);
        m_Annot.setRectangle(currRect);

        requestLayout();
        postInvalidate();
    }

    protected void finishDrawing() {
        super.finishDrawing();


        mNotesView.getPageView(0).addAnnot(
            (com.qoppa.android.pdf.annotations.b.b) stamp);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mStampImage, drawingMatrix, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsFillColor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v == mStampButton) {
        mSaveDocButton.setClickable(true);
         mNotesView.startDrawingTool(new ImageDrawingTool(this));
        int pgNo = mNotesView.getCurrentPageNumber();
        Log.e("Pgno","sing"+pgNo);
        //PDFPage page = mNotesView.getDocument().getPage(pgNo - 1);
        //Log.e("page","sing"+page);
        RubberStamp stamp = AnnotationFactory
                .createRubberStamp(mStampImage);
        Log.e("stamp","sing"+stamp);
        stamp.setBorderWidth(2);
        stamp.setRectangle(new RectF(20, 80, 100, 100));
        //mNotesView.startDrawingTool(new ImageDrawingTool(this));  
        mNotesView.startDrawingTool(new ImageDrawingTool(this));    
    }

    if (v == mSaveDocButton) {

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        Log.e("sing1","sing"+ adb);
        adb.setTitle("Are you Sure?");
        adb.setIcon(R.drawable.apollo_emr_logo);
        adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                PDFDocument doc = mNotesView.getDocument();
                Log.e("sing11","sing"+doc);
                int totalPg = doc.getPageCount();
                Log.e("Total pg count",""+totalPg);
                for (int i = 0; i < totalPg; i++) {
                    PDFPage page = doc.getPage(i);
                    Log.e("sing111","sing"+ page);

                    try {
                        page.flattenAnnotations(true);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PDFViewer.this,
                                PDFViewer.class);

                startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (PDFException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                mNotesView.save("/sdcard/time.pdf");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(PDFViewer.this,
                                PDFViewer.class);

                startActivity(intent);
                // mNotesView.save("/mnt/sdcard/" + pdfFilename);
                dialog.cancel();


                //new uploadFilesTask().execute(pdfDataStr);
            }
        });
        adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        adb.show();

    }
}
```

}

And log file is

```
12-26 18:56:32.460: E/Pgno(19019): sing1
12-26 18:56:32.468: E/stamp(19019): singcom.qoppa.android.pdf.annotations.b.g@42a4ddb8
12-26 18:56:33.252: E/Pgno(19019): sing1
12-26 18:56:33.256: E/stamp(19019): singcom.qoppa.android.pdf.annotations.b.g@42a63710
12-26 18:56:34.835: E/sing1(19019): singandroid.app.AlertDialog$Builder@42a6ac28
12-26 18:56:36.084: E/sing11(19019): singcom.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFDocument@429cd510
12-26 18:56:36.084: E/Total pg count(19019): 1
12-26 18:56:36.085: E/sing111(19019): singcom.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFPage@42a14ed0
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019): Process: com.example.qpdfdemo, PID: 19019
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=19019, uid=10147
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2406)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1256)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:365)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at com.qoppa.viewer.c.b$_b.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at com.qoppa.viewer.c.b$_b.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-26 18:56:36.353: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

you must instantiate mNotesView before listner on the buttons

Comment: Welcome to SO. In the stack trace posted, the error was Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast. Perhaps that's something you should address in your answer as well. Perhaps the user forgot to add permission in the manifest also.